# Cakephp route matches everything

Tags: cakephp, url-routing

I have following route added to `routes.php` in the end.

```
Router::connect('/:sellername/:itemtitle',
                 array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'view_item_detail'),
                 array(
                      'pass' => array('sellername','itemtitle'),
                      'sellername' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                      'itemtitle' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                  )
               );
```

So this matches the dynamic urls like `http://example.com/john/title-of-an-item`
Problem is this also matches every other url like `http://example.com/members/signin` even though there's a `MembersController` controller and `signin` action in it. 
I can fix it using following route entry.

```
Router::connect(
                 '/members/:action',
                 array('controller' => 'members')                      
               );
```

But it's very tedious to add every route like above.
Doesn't existing matching controller names are prioritized while making a match?
Do order of routes in `routes.php` matter?

Comment: how many sellers do you have/expect ? If it's a large number you should choose between defining a `/:controller` (etc) route and simply ensuring all user routes contain a static string e.g. `/u/:seller/:item` or `:seller/:item/xyz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Custom Route classes` is to help you

Custom route classes allow you to extend and change how individual routes parse requests and handle reverse routing. A route class should extend CakeRoute and implement one or both of match() and/or parse(). parse() is used to parse requests and match() is used to handle reverse routing.

You can use a custom route class when making a route by using the routeClass option, and loading the file containing your route before trying to use it:

```
Router::connect(
     '/:slug',
      array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'),
      array('routeClass' => 'SlugRoute')
);
```

This route would create an instance of SlugRoute and allow you to implement custom parameter handling.

[custome routing class let you impliment anything](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes)

`But personal opinion is to user a static and meaning full text in the url that diffrenciate it from the rest.`